# Selecting all records from table untill column will be null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to select all users from custom departments. Each department can have more important department above itself, but there is also possibility that department can be kind of main department.

Example with main department (main department column checked)

- First department
- **Second department under first department** < This one is main department

  - Third department under second department
  - Fourth department under second department

    - Fifth department under fourth department

Now we need to show users from second, third, fourth and fifth department.

Users table has: **department_id**, which means to which department user belongs.

Departments table has: **department_id**, **department_id_above** and **is_main_department** columns.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Ok, I've updated question, but with this query the problem is that I even don't know where to put my fingers to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've written so far the below could be of help. But this is just from guessing.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL

Have you tried it?

Comment: Ok, I've made this query basing on example which you send. It took a while but now it's ok. Thanks.

Comment: great to hear it helped! :)